# how to estimate the gas cost of a contract function that will fail

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py, gas-estimate

I am trying to estimate the gas cost of a contract function that will fail. when i do that using standard `web3.py`'s `contract.function(args).estimateGas(txArgs)` it ends up failing and raising an exception and i don't get the actual gas cost.
is there a way to do get the gas cost ? does this depend on the node i am using ?